# Postgres database queries from express server time out after multiple select queries

Tags: postgresql, api, server

I'm running a node (express) rest API, a postgres database and an indexer that fills the database all on the same server.

For some reason when I do a lot of queries to the db from the rest api, after a certain amount of queries all of the following queries start timing out. It doesn't seem like there are any locks and I need to restart my docker container to make the db return again.

I added some logs in my rest api to see where things seem to timeout:

```
        console.log("get here1")
        pool.query(totalQuery, [], (error, results) => {
                console.log("get here2");
                if (error) {
                        console.error(error)
                        res.status(404).json(error)
                }

                const total_markets = results.rows[0] ? results.rows[0].total_markets : 0;

                pool.query(query, values, (error, results) => {
                        console.log("get here3");
                  if (error) {
                          console.error(error)
                          res.status(404).json(error)
                  }

                  res.status(200).json({count: total_markets, data: results.rows})
          })
        });
```

The server logs read as follows:

```
get here2
get here3
get here
get here2
get here3
get here
get here
get here
get here
```

I'm really not sure what is causing my queries to timeout but it does seem like the entire database is inaccessible.

When I attach to the docker container and use `psql` to query the database, the queries work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a node.js(pg more specifically issue)

I added timeout attributes to the pool config:

````
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.CONNECTION_STRING ? process.env.CONNECTION_STRING : connectionString,
  ssl: production,
  max : 5,
  connectionTimeoutMillis : 5000,
  idleTimeoutMillis : 30000
});```
````